# Scraping with Python

Tags: python, screen-scraping

I need to get the data from a toll table in Argentina. The website where this information is located [here](https://www.argentina.gob.ar/obras-publicas/vialidad-nacional/institucional/informacion-publica/tarifas-de-peajes)

Now, I try to put together the code to bring the information that is inside the "tbody", and the "tr" and "td" to be able to create a list and then a dataframe with that information but every time I try to bring the information from the " tbody", brings up very little data. It is impossible for me to get the information from the rows of the table. I leave you the code:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.argentina.gob.ar/obras-publicas/vialidad-nacional/institucional/informacion-publica/tarifas-de-peajes'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')
rows = soup.find('table',attrs={"class":"table table-spaced table-align-middle table-mobile"}).find_all('tbody')
rows
```

This code returns the following:

```
[<tbody class="list" id="show-data"></tbody>]
```

I've tried fetching the "tr" and "td" elements directly but can't fetch the rows. Does anyone know what I could be doing wrong?

From already thank you very much!

Comment: It looks like, for this specific website, JavaScript is used to load the table data a few moments after the page loads. Unfortunately the requests library cannot run this JavaScript to fetch the data, it just fetches the static HTML. I would recommend using the Python Selenium library instead of requests as it has the ability to use a browser engine to run the JavaScript and wait for the data to load.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply!

I figured that the requests being made with JS were complicating the extraction, but due to my lack of experience I wasn't sure. Thank you very much for the suggestion!